# App Engine: storing imgs on Picasa or Flickr or

Tags: image, google-app-engine

Briefly: ***Is there a way to post images to Picasa or Flickr from my GAE app without OAuth?***

I am writing a web-application on Google App Engine in Java. Naturally, i want to stay within their quotas (at least for the time being), and i want to allow users to add images to their posts. The images will be transient (i.e. they don't need to be stored for long).

In this respect i would like to store my images on some third-party image hosting on one user account, mine (or, rather, my application's).

I looked into several image hostings (Flickr, Photobucket, Picasa, Tinypic), and all of them offer authentication via OAuth, which would be perfect if i wanted the users to post images to *their* albums.

Is there a way to post an image to any of these (or another robust) service in a simple manner (ie providing my login, password, image bytes and its type and receiving the url of the pic back)?

Thank you in advance ;)
Timofey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact answer depends on which service, of course, but most services are deprecating non-OAuth APIs in favor of OAuth based ones.

Since you want to store images under your own account, though, you could simply go through the OAuth dance once, store the resulting key and token in your app, and use them for all requests.

This seems like a lot of hoops and trouble to jump through for storing temporary images, though. 1GB of temporary images will cost you $0.10/month on App Engine - is your time as a developer worth so little that you value it less than that?

Comment: Thanks.
Since OAuth is the only way, it really isn't worth the effort.